# Spring MVC @Path variable with { } braces

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Am developing an application using spring boot. In REST controller i prefer to use path variable(`@PathVariabale` annotation). My code fetching the path variable but it contatins **{ }** braces as it is in the url. Please any one suggest me to solve this issue

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user/item/{loginName}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void getSourceDetails(@PathVariable String loginName) {
    try {
        System.out.println(loginName);
        // it print like this  {john}
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.error(e);
    }
}
```

URL

```
http://localhost:8080/user/item/{john}
```

Out put in controller

{john}

Comment: What do you want it to print?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis i need john instead of {john}

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Use `http://localhost:8080/user/item/john` to submit your request instead.

You give Spring a value of "{john}" to the path variable `loginName`, so Spring get it with the "{}"

[Web MVC framework](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html)  states that

> ### URI Template Patterns
>
> URI templates can be used for convenient access to selected parts of a
>   URL in a @RequestMapping method.
>
> A URI Template is a **URI-like string**, containing one or more variable
>   names. **When you substitute values for these variables, the template
>   becomes a URI**. The proposed RFC for URI Templates defines how a URI is
>   parameterized. For example, the URI Template
>   http://www.example.com/users/{userId} **contains the variable userId**.
>   **Assigning the value fred to the variable yields
>   http://www.example.com/users/fred.**
>
> In Spring MVC you can use the @PathVariable annotation on a method
>   argument to bind it to the value of a URI template variable:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/owners/{ownerId}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
 public String findOwner(@PathVariable String ownerId, Model model) {
     Owner owner = ownerService.findOwner(ownerId);
     model.addAttribute("owner", owner);
     return "displayOwner"; 
  }
```

> The URI Template " /owners/{ownerId}" specifies the variable name
>   ownerId. When the controller handles this request, the value of
>   ownerId is set to the value found in the appropriate part of the URI.
>   For example, when a request comes in for /owners/fred, the value of
>   ownerId is fred.