# How to configure properly the @PathVariable parameter in Spring RESTful app?

Tags: java, regex, spring, rest

I'm working on a Spring RESTful app and it has MVC architecture. The 3 layers are following: dao, service and controller. The controller layer ( package ) is responsible to provide JSON data with respective URL. The following method in the Controller package works but breaks in certain input values,

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/category/{category}", method =  RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<String> getGivenCategory(@PathVariable String category){

    HttpHeaders ResultHeader = new HttpHeaders();
    ResultHeader.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    ResultHeader.set("Content-Type", "application/json");
    String result = productsService.getGivenCategory(category);  

    if(null ==  result){

        return new ResponseEntity<String>( "{}", ResultHeader, HttpStatus.EXPECTATION_FAILED);
     }
     return new ResponseEntity<String>(result, ResultHeader, HttpStatus.OK); 
 }
```

The method works fine with usual Strings such as "MASONRY COATINGS" or "SOS FAUCETS". So, the call in the browser in will be,

```
http://localhost:8080/searchAPI/category/MASONRY%20COATINGS
```

However, for some Strings the URL breaks down such as "PLYWOOD - SANDED/FINISHED". I assume with using certain regex the issue can be solved, but, my knowledge is very limited in that context. Any suggestion how can I improrve the code ?

Comment: This may sound like a cop-out, but can you try to not use path strings which will break the framework?  Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26794198/spring-mvc-path-variable-with-braces) for an article which has this thinking.

Comment: What is the URL for "PLYWOOD - SANDED/FINISHED"? Did you encode the `/` character?

Comment: No, I was also thinking the issue arise with / character. How can I encode / ?

Comment: `PLYWOOD%20-%20SANDED%2FFINISHED` would be the encoded URL

Comment: Seems related to this  [https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-11101](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-11101)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add CharacterEncodingFilter filter to your web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Okay, but, how to use this with the method I have mentioned ?