# Spring MVC @Path variable with null value

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

[image]Am developing an application using spring boot. In Resource am using path variable(`**@PathVariable**` annotation) and Request Param(`**@RequestParam("name")**` annotation). My code fetching the request param value but not the path variable value,I am getting the path variable value as null. Please any one suggest me to solve this issue.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/user/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)  
public void get(@RequestParam("name")  String name, @PathVariable Integer id); {

        System.out.println("name="+name);
        System.out.println("id="+id)
}
```

**URL:**
http://localhost:8080/api/user/2?name=neeru

**OUTPUT:**
name=neeru
id=null

i also tried

```
**@RequestMapping(value = "/api/user/id={id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)**
```

**URL:**
http://localhost:8080/api/user/id=2?name=neeru
 but getting same id value=null

i have added one more method -only has `@PathVariable`

```
@RequestMapping(path="/api/user/name/{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)    
   void get( @PathVariable("value=name") String name){

   System.out.println("name="+name)
}
```

but result is same path variable value  name=null

Comment: could you try api/user/{id} instead of api/user/id={id}?

Comment: yes,i tried   api/user/id={id}?name=abc but getting same null value for id

Comment: Set a name for the pathvariable like @PathVariable(name="id") so it can get resolved..

Comment: yes tried @PathVariable(name="id")  and also @PathVariable(value="id") ,both are not working

Comment: You have a typo... should be @PathVariable(value="name") and not  @PathVariable("value=name")

Comment: i don't think this config is wrong, pls make sure your controller accessing ulr is right .

Comment: yes,url is right because request param is working fine

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. **@PathVariable** is to obtain some placeholder from the uri
2. **@RequestParam** is to obtain an parameter

Change your endpoint like this

http://localhost:8080/api/user/2/users?name=neeru

`

```
@RequestMapping(value = "api/user/{id}/users", method = RequestMethod.GET)  
public void get(@RequestParam("name")  String name, @PathVariable("id") Integer id); {
        System.out.println("name="+name);
        System.out.println("id="+id)
}
```

`

Output:

name = neeru

id = 2

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: not working tried,@RequestMapping(path="api/user/{id}/users", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 void get(@RequestParam("name")  String name, @PathVariable("id") Integer id);  and url : http://localhost:8080/api/user/id/2/users?name=neeru

Comment: may be,sorry but not working for me. here is also a ex https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26794198/spring-mvc-path-variable-with-braces . i have done same ,but dont know why its not working

Comment: see my question ,i have attached screenshot,tell me where m doing mistake

Comment: thanks,actually i had UserResource interface and UserResourceImpl class ,In spring boot PathVariable  annotation is not inherited from interface, i was using @PathVariable at interface thats why is was not working but  now m using  PathVariable annotation at UserResouceImpl as well,now its working for me.

Answer (score 5):

@PathVariable is used for extracting variables in the path like MystyxMac suggested. If you want to extract query parameters then you must use @RequestParam

But your example is a mix of path and query parameter.

You cannot use = in an URL because this is a reserved character: https://www.w3.org/Addressing/URL/url-spec.txt

So either use

```
/api/user/{id} with @PathVariable
```

or

```
/api/user?id={id} with @RequestParam
```

Comment: m trying /api/user/{id} with @PathVariable  but getting null value for id,dont know why i am getting path variable value as null

Comment: im trying to write API test cases for scenarios like this. if the endpoint is called as /api/user/null should it give a client error (4xx) or a server error (5xx)?

Comment: Always a 4xx becuase 5xx is server error that indicates that your application has an error