# Wrapper type Path variable won't accept null value - Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, null, integer, wrapper, path-variables

This is our **Controller**

```
@GetMapping(path = "/getUsersForHierarchy/{entity}/{hierId}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<List<UserInfo>> getUsersForHierarchy(@PathVariable(name = "entity", required = true) int entity,
            @PathVariable(name = "hierId", required = true) Integer hierId) {

    ..................

    ..................

}
```

We are expecting two `Path variables`, one is of `int` type (entity) and the other is `Integer` type (hierId). `hierId` can be null or any numeric value and thats why its kept as `Wrapper`. But its gives error while firing the request like this

**http://localhost:5010/v1/accountholder/userinfo/getUsersForHierarchy/5/null**

Now a Wrapper is meant to accept `null` values, but we are getting error like this

**Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Integer'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "null"**

If we change Integer to String the call is getting inside the controller, but for further proceedings we need to use Integer.

We looked into this [Spring MVC @Path variable with null value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46928053/spring-mvc-path-variable-with-null-value), and tried invoking the API with change in URL like this

**http://localhost:5010/v1/accountholder/userinfo/getUsersForHierarchy/5/blaaa/null**, but the error is still the same.

What should be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it to be nullable you can achieve it with the following. First of all, if it's nullable the required property should be `false`. Also, considering `required = true` is the default, there's no need to specify it and if the name of the path variable matches the name of the corresponding variable you don't have to specify the name either.

```java
@GetMapping(value = {
        "/getUsersForHierarchy/{entity}/", 
        "/getUsersForHierarchy/{entity}/{hierId}"
    },
    produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<List<UserInfo>> getUsersForHierarchy(
    @PathVariable int entity,
    @PathVariable(required = false) Integer hierId) {

}
```

Considering I don't like to deliberately allow a null value into the application, another nice to have could be having the `hierId` required with type `Optional`, so the following will give you a `Optional.empty` when just `/getUsersForHierarchy/123/` is invoked and `hierId` is null. Otherwise it will populate the optional when `hierId` is provided invoking `/getUsersForHierarchy/123/321`:

```java
@GetMapping(value = {
        "/getUsersForHierarchy/{entity}/", 
        "/getUsersForHierarchy/{entity}/{hierId}"
    },
    produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<List<UserInfo>> getUsersForHierarchy(
    @PathVariable int entity,
    @PathVariable Optional<Integer> hierId) {

}
```

Comment: Second approach is working, but first one is not. Thanks

Comment: @ArunSudhakaran more details? What's not working? What's the error? Just copied pasted the code from here and it works just fine. Which get call are you doing? If the second is working, the first is working as well, the only difference is the type of the variable and the required.

Comment: The first approach is throwing the same error which I was getting earlier

Comment: @ArunSudhakaran again, can we have more details? Are you actually passing the value "null" in the URL?

Comment: No, I wasn't passing it