# How to change url get method in form?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I want to make a search function that will filter data by type of letter.

Form:

```
<form action="/viewall/filterBy" th:object="${letter}" method="get">
    <table class="table table-bordered" style="width:100%">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
               <th>
                    <select class="form-control" id="type_form" th:field="*{id_type}" name="id_type">
                        <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="0">--Select--</option>
                        <option th:each="type : ${letter_types}" th:value="${type.id}" th:text="${type.name}"></option>
                    </select>
               </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>    
                    <button style="display: block" class="btn btn-info"> <i class="fa fa-search"></i> Search</button>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

Controller

```
@RequestMapping (value="/viewall/filterBy", method= RequestMethod.GET) public String filterBy(Model model,@ModelAttribute("letter") LetterModel letter, @RequestParam(value="id_type", required=true) Integer id_type)  {
    ....
    return "letter-view"; 
}
```

If I execute, the URL is below:

> http://localhost:8080/viewall/filterBy?id_type=3

My question is, Is it possible to change the URL, so it become

> http://localhost:8080/viewall/filterBy/3

Thank you in advance. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring MVC @Path variable with { } braces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26794198/spring-mvc-path-variable-with-braces)

Comment: @soon well, i think it's different because the param in {} - in my case - is taken from form.
please enlight

Comment: @natadecoco what difference does it makes if you are taking data from form?

Comment: @natadecoco The question I linked explains how to grab value from the url

Answer (score 1):

You can have the following url type:

```
http://localhost:8080/viewall/filterBy/3
```

then your `Controller` mapping will be like the following:

```
@RequestMapping (value="/viewall/filterBy/{id_type}", method= RequestMethod.GET) 
public String filterBy(Model model, @PathVariable(name = "id_type") int idType)  {
    ....
    return "letter-view"; 
}
```

**or more simplified approach:**

```
@GetMapping (value="/viewall/filterBy/id_type/{id}") 
public String filterBy(Model model, @PathVariable(name = "id") int idType)  {
    ....
    return "letter-view"; 
}
```

**UPDATE**

Now since your URL pattern has changed you have to submit the form via javascript. You have to concat the selected value to your URL and then submit the form. To submit the form via javascript see the following codes:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

   <select class="form-control" id="type_form" th:field="*{id_type}" name="id_type">
     <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="0">--Select--</option>
     <option th:each="type : ${letter_types}" th:value="${type.id}" th:text="${type.name}"></option>
   </select>

   <button onclick="submitForm()"> SUBMIT </button> <!--this will call the submitForm() javascript function given below -->

  <script type="text/javascript">
      function submitForm() {

          var selectedOption = document.getElementById("type_form"); // the <select> is assigned to the variable using its id

          window.location = "/viewall/filterBy/" + selectedOption.value; // here we concat the url with the selected  option and assign it to the action of the form
      }
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it's not working yet. 
How about form action in template?

Comment: you can post your form using javascript.

Comment: you can accept the answer as solution to your question.

Comment: thank you @sam. however the url become 
http://localhost:8080viewall/filterBy/1?id_type=1 
if button submit is clicked
(it also can access http://localhost:8080viewall/filterBy/1)